# Issue with binding dynamically generated buttons with lambda in kivy

Tags: python, for-loop, button, lambda, kivy

I'm writing a data scraper for my school that displays information live in an app form. I'm trying to create buttons in a for loop, use lambda to bind each button to a function and a value to use when calling (in this case, to print their value for testing), add each button (as well as a couple other widgets) to a layout and add this layout to the screen.

For some reason, however, although I should be saving the value of "a" in the lambda function: `btn.bind(on_press=lambda btn, a=a: self.getlink(a))`, lambda cannot seem to "remember" more than around 3 iterations back (this loop goes for about 20 cycles). The last three buttons (most recently generated) on the screen return correct values, but the further you go up on the screen (a kivy RecycleView layout), the less accurate the value. When I press the first few buttons on the screen, literally nothing happens. As I go down the screen pressing buttons, I occasionally get a random number spit out, sometimes a significantly different number (spits out 2 when it should be 11 for example).

There are no errors being thrown back when I run it, and everything else works just fine. I just cannot seem to get these buttons to bind to the proper value. I even tried using a counter in the loop that adds one for every iteration and using that instead of a, but it did the same thing.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Here is the relevant code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder


class ScreenThree(RecycleView, Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenThree, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'padding': '7sp',
                      'size_hint': (6, None),
                      'allow_stretch': True,
                      'height': ((Window.height / 4) * (22))}]

    def screenlength(self):
        return Window.height * (20 / 4)

    def screenSize(self, modifier=1):
        window_s = Window.size
        if window_s[1] >= window_s[0]:
            return str((window_s[0] * 0.007) * modifier) + 'sp'
        else:
            return str((window_s[1] * 0.007) * modifier) + 'sp'


class ScreenFour(TabbedPanel, Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenFour, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.default_tab_text = 'Events'
        self.tab_width = Window.width / 2.7
        self.tab_height = Window.height / 25
        self.default_tab_content = ScreenThree()
        self.background_color = (0, 0, 0, 1)

    def screenSize(self, modifier=1):
        window_s = Window.size
        if window_s[1] >= window_s[0]:
            return str((window_s[0] * 0.007) * modifier) + 'sp'
        else:
            return str((window_s[1] * 0.007) * modifier) + 'sp'


class AddWidget(GridLayout, Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for a in range(20):
            asyncimage1 = AsyncImage(source='https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51zLZbEVSTL._AC_SX679_.jpg',
                                     allow_stretch=True,
                                     size_hint_y=None,
                                     size_hint_x=5,
                                     height=Window.height / 4)
            self.add_widget(asyncimage1)
            label = Label(text='title goes here',
                          bold=True,
                          text_size=self.size,
                          size_hint=(1, 1),
                          valign='top',
                          padding=(0, '11sp'),
                          font_size=self.screenSize(1.2))
            label.bind(size=label.setter('text_size'))
            layout2 = GridLayout(rows=3)
            label2 = Label(text='date goes here',
                           text_size=self.size,
                           size_hint=(1, 1),
                           valign='top',
                           padding=(0, '1sp'),
                           font_size=self.screenSize(0.9))
            label2.bind(size=label2.setter('text_size'))
            layout2.add_widget(label)
            layout2.add_widget(label2)
            btn = Button(text='Visit Website',
                         font_size=self.screenSize(1.4),
                         size_hint=(1, 1),
                         id = str(a),
                         padding=("10sp", "10sp"))
            btn.bind(on_press=lambda btn, a=a: self.getlink(a))
            layout2.add_widget(btn)
            self.add_widget(layout2)

    def getlink(self, position):
        print(position)

    def screenSize(self, modifier=1):
        window_s = Window.size
        if window_s[1] >= window_s[0]:
            return str((window_s[0] * 0.007) * modifier) + 'sp'
        else:
            return str((window_s[1] * 0.007) * modifier) + 'sp'

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

pres1 = runTouchApp(Builder.load_file('screenskv2.kv'))

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement

MyApp().run()
```

And the relevant code in the kv file:

```
  #:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

ScreenManagement:
    ScreenThree:

<AddWidget>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    cols:2
    spacing: '10sp'
    col_default_width: (Window.width/2)-50

<ScreenThree>:
    name: 'screen_three'
    rv_layout: 'layout'
    viewclass: 'AddWidget'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        id: 'layout'
        pos_hint_x: 0
        size_hint: (None, None)
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal runnable example?

Comment: The full project has 4 py files 1 kv file and 5 JSON files, im not sure i can upload everything, although I could probably upload enough to get just the one section working if that works

Comment: Post the minimal needed to run just your problem.

Comment: I just edited the original post to include all necessary components to run the issue